# merge data vector to shapefile data slot

Tags: r, gis

i try do add economic data to a shapefile using `merge` and the 2 digit ISO code as ID. The code looks somewhat like this:

```
library(maptools)
library(foreign)
library(sp)
library(lattice)
library(shapefiles)

world.shp<-readShapePoly("world_shapefile.shp")

world.shp@data<-merge(world.shp@data, data.frame(country=iso.code.vector, net=country.data.vector), by.x="ISO2", by.y="country", all.x=TRUE, sort=FALSE)
```

Unfortunately this ruins the order of the .shp file even though i put the `sort` argument. A plot afterwards shows me that the data does not match the polygons like it should. What am i doing wrong?

i got the world map data from [thematicmapping.org](http://thematicmapping.org/downloads/world_borders.php)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Merge will always break the sp object. Here are two ways to merge a dataframe to the sp @data datframe.

```
shape@data = data.frame(shape@data, OtherData[match(sdata@data$IDS, OtherData$IDS),])
```

Where; shape is your shape file, IDS is the identifier you want to merge on and OtherData is the dataframe that you want to combine with shape. Note that IDS can be different names in the two datasets but need to actually be the same values (not fuzzy).

Alternatively you can use this function.

```
join.sp.df <- function(x, y, xcol, ycol) {
  x$sort_id <- 1:nrow(as(x, "data.frame"))  
    x.dat <- as(x, "data.frame")  
     x.dat2 <- merge(x.dat, y, by.x = xcol, by.y = ycol)  
    x.dat2.ord <- x.dat2[order(x.dat2$sort_id), ]  
  x2 <- x[x$sort_id %in% x.dat2$sort_id, ]  
  x2.dat <- as(x2, "data.frame") 
    row.names(x.dat2.ord) <- row.names(x2.dat)  
  x2@data <- x.dat2.ord  
  return(x2)
}
```

Where; x=sp SpatialDataFrame object, y=dataframe object to merge with x, xcol=Merge column name in sp object (need to quote), ycol=Merge column name in dataframe object (need to quote)

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem when using R versions 2.12.x and 2.13.x, but the problem appears to have been resolved in version 2.15.1.

Comment: Later I found that merge will always ruin the order. The solution was to add a new column to the data (call it 'index'), number it artificially from 1 to n, do what you need to do with your original data (merge, etc), and as a last step sort it back according to your 'index' column.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround. Not very elegant actually and it takes some time to execute but it works:

```
world.shp<-readShapePoly("world_shapefile.shp")

net<-rep(NA,length(world.shp@data$NAME))

for(i in 1:length(net))
{
    for(j in 1:length(iso.code.vector))
    {
        if(!is.na(world.shp@data$ISO2[i])){if(world.shp@data$ISO2[i]==iso.code.vector[j]){net[i]=country.data.vector[j]}}
    }
}

world.shp@data<-data.frame(world.shp@data, net)
```